# Elastic limit tempered steel

Tags: elasticity

What is the elastic limit of tempered steel?

I have to calculate the maximum charge that can be applied to a tempered steel wire of $0.08\ m$ of diameter without it exceeding its elastic limit

I am given the formula $EL=\dfrac{F_m} {A} $ where $EL$ is the elastic limit, $F_m$ is the maximum charge and $A$ is the area

I am also given the Young coefficient $Y=40\times10^{10}\  \dfrac{N}{m^2}$ to calculate the elongation the wire will suffer.

But I cannot find the elastic limit.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Commenters, please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: But I'm asking for an specific number that I cannot find on the books...

Comment: @DavidZ - Obviiously I haven't seen these comments that were removed. But there are times when a comment can and should be used for an answer. For example, if the answer is just a link to another post or to Wikipedia. Or if the answer is just a short sentence like "The elastic limit is x". Things like that tend to get down voted if posted as an answer.

Comment: What is charge here?

Comment: @mmesser314 A link to another post with no further information is not an answer; however, a short sentence like "the elastic limit is x" is most definitely an answer and should _not_ be posted as a comment. Under normal circumstances those comments are likely to be deleted and that's the extent of it. But, if we (mods) found someone repeatedly leaving those comments even though they should be expected to know better, that person could be subject to the same disciplinary measures that accompany other violations of site rules.